# Foundation 4 tooltip change top value

Tags: css, html, tooltip, zurb-foundation

I want to change tool tip text top value. because it is hovering on icons.
Check screenshots for better view the issue.
If any other issue in formatting my HTML text, please let me know. 
(I have embedded the perfect-scrollbar in this)

[image: When hover this happens]
[image: this is code for html (firebug screenshot)]

Comment: need more code..post a link if possible

Comment: can not post link bro. I will paste code here bro. Tell me which code is more required here.
Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

More of your code would be a help for sure.

From experience with f-dropdown menu's within foundation I have given the main element a position or absolute and then defined the proper distance where I wanted it. This might be different with hover tooltips but it is worth a shot!